# Purple texture in cycles problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine

i've got the problem with cycles. Evee works fine, but all textures in cycles are purple. For example simple checkers. I'm new to blender, but saw a ton of videos about missing texture files, but thay all in place. I've completly lost there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmm your material output in the first picture is set to cycles only but the second one is something different set to All? That shouldn't be the problem, I am just a bit confused, can you share this file with https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: The first picture. You are not in render view.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html

> **Material Preview**
>
> Render the 3D Viewport with **EEVEE** and an HDRI environment. This
> mode is particularly suited for previewing materials and texture
> painting. You can select different lighting conditions to test your
> materials.
>
> **Rendered**
>
> Render the 3D Viewport with the scene Render Engine, for interactive
> rendering. By default the scene lights are used for lighting. An HDRI
> environment can be used as well, with the same options as Material
> Preview mode.

The material preview mode using the EEVEE engine. Regardless what is your selected render engine in the drop down list.
Press <kbd>Z</kbd>, select *Rendered*.

Or

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some times if Blender crashes or shuts down unexpectedly you need to reload your textures.

In top menu *File > External Data > Reload Missing Files*.

In the *Image Editor* you have in  <kbd>N</kbd> key tool panel, under *Image*  you can check the path to image is correctly

[image]

Comment: The OP is using a *Checker* procedural texture, which doesn't use image based textures or external files.

Comment: did you use enviromental texture? If he is not loaded it shaining purple to object.